# Data Import Wizard doesnt show custom field of a custom object

Tags: data-import-wizard

[image]Data Import Wizard doesn't show custom field of a custom object.

All the fields have its Field level security set for Admin Profile.
even though i cannot see fields in native import wizard.
i have 7 fields among which only 2 are automatically mapped other are not visible

I haven't created a tab for the custom object, will it be a issue.

Please let me know which part i'm going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check Field accessibility, it should not be hidden.

Comment: Its not hidden in the pagelayout

Comment: For all the 5 fields i have Field Accessibility to Editable .

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I have found a solution. The new Data Import Wizard picks the default record type and page layout as the controller for the visibility. You need to go to the profile and check what is the default record type and check if that record type page layout has the custom fields visible.

It worked for me.

Comment: it didnt work for me changing the defualt record type, but it worked when i added into the other page layout, just in case it helps anyone else

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue listed on salesforce site

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jjYUAAY

Answer (score 1):

The Data Import Wizard uses page layouts and field-level security to determine the fields available on import.

In order for a field to be visible within the Data Import Wizard, it must be available to the user within the page layout and field-level security. This applies to end users as well as users with a System Administrator profile.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the field and click on this button for the field and check it should be editable for the profile you are using.

[image]

For the auto-mapping your column name in CSV file should be same as Label or API Name of field

Comment: For all the 5 fields i have Field Accessibility to Editable.

Comment: You are saying, it is not auto mapped, are you not able to map them manually as well?

Comment: I am not able to view the fields itself.

Comment: Please look into the snapshot

Comment: Can you attach screen shot of columns in CSV file and fields you are trying to import in salesforce, also check datatype of those fields

Comment: all the fields datatype are text.

Answer (score 0):

Fields must be visible to the profile of the logged in user. Click on the fields that are not visible and click on the View **Field Accessibility** Button and check against the profile of logged in user, it should not be hidden.

Comment: This was the error causing my issue in a scratch org.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with lookup fields. I went back to the Import your Data into Salesforce step of the wizard and mapped these lookup fields to the data type here and they were then available to map on the next page.

Comment: This appears to be essentially the same as Alberto Del Rio's answer from 4.5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

What has not been mentioned here is that on the page where you select Add or Update. You must scroll down the page to select the appropriate record type.

This solved the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Updating/Checking the profile and field level security for editable permission is not sufficient for some reason you need to make it visible on the page layout as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can select Record Type under Add/Update options in the Data Import Wizard. That would open up more options available for a specific record type which could be missing on your default profile record type.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contribution is appreciated, but this appears to be essentially the same as @Tunde 's answer from almost 1 year ago. Can you please explain/expound on how your answer is different?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone in the future: If this problem is only for NON Admins, then a setting in the profile called 'Import Custom Objects' (setup--> profile --> system permission --> Import Custom Objects) can also help.